# "Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship" error when trying to list tags in Tag model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add a Tag model to Django rest framework. The model is extremely simple:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, primary_key=True)
```

as well as the Serializer:

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = '__all__'
```

and View:

```
class TagView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tag.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TagSerializer
```

urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'tag', views.TagView)


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'))
]
```

After that I can access a particular tag, for example:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/tag/SharePoint/

But I cannot list all of them:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/tag

Results in this error:

> Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name
>   "tag-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your
>   API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this
>   field.

Do I have to add an id field to the model?

Comment: Add your router register code

Comment: @AjayTomGeorge done